# LINQ to SQL Equivalent of ISDATE() in T-SQL and casting?

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

Does anyone know the equivalent of ISDATE() in LINQ to SQL query syntax? I've got a varchar field in SQL that contains dates and I need to filter out the non-date rows.

was hoping for something like this:

```
var query = SomeDataContext;
    query = from p in query
    where p.ISDATE(field1) == true;
    select p;
```

also, how would one cast something for SQL in Linq syntax?

```
CAST(SomeDate AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick to doing this is to create a user function in the database which merely calls ISDATE as returns the value

```
  CREATE FUNCTION My_ISDATE(@maybeDate varchar(max))
  returns bit
  as return ISDATE(@maybeDate);
```

Then add My_IsDate to you database context, and use it in you query:

```
var db = SomeDataContext;
var query = from p in db.MyTable
where db.My_ISDATE(p.field1)
select p;
```

Comment: cool, that looks like it could work. how would one merge the query sequences from 2 different context? by joining the tables? of different types? sorry if this seems like a novice question. i'm fairly new to DLINQ. I'm taking advantage of the deferred execution of LINQtoSQL to build up my queries.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an extension method that maps to ISDATE when using LINQ to SQL.

If you are ok with loading all the data and then doing the filtering in the client space, then use TryParse on the field and compare to the date.

Otherwise, I would create a stored procedure which would return the data you want (so that you can use ISDATE), and then execute that through the context.

Also, your syntax for the use of ISDATE is incorrect.  ISDATE just tells you if the expression is a valid date format.  Your query would look like this:

```
var query = SomeDataContext;
    query = from p in query
    where ISDATE(field1) != 0 && CONVERT(datetime, field1) > some date
    select p;
```

The syntax isn't valid, but it gives you an idea of how to form the query.

Comment: I might try using TryParse, but the return set is pretty big. I'll see how the performance will be. thanks.

Comment: @steven: I really suggest you try the SP route, as if the result set is large, you are going to get killed on performance.

Answer (score 2):

A problem with SO is that an increasing number of threads on answers of problems contain outdated answers, mostly because they are not touched in years. However in combination with a search engine (e.g. Google) who then returns as #1 a link (for instance this post) when you query "How should i use IsDate in Linq" it needs someone to then add one answer (at the bottom with 0 votes) of the latest correct answer.

:: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/8488 >

It now has been added to EF.Functions so you can simply do:

```
Where(x=>  EF.Functions.IsDate(x.somefield))
```

Comment: Absolutely the way in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can do it. Links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386973.aspx

this might be of help but I haven't watched it:

http://mtaulty.com/videos/nuggets/l2s/15_mt_l2s_callingsqlfunctions.wmv

Full list here:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2007/05/10/9322.aspx